# Out-Of-Band Pairing between iOS device and embedded Linux

Tags: ios, linux, bluez, carplay, bluetooth-oob

I'm implementing OOB Pairing between **iOS 10** device (iPhone) and **embedded Linux** device (3.10 kernel version, **5.35 BlueZ** version) via USB (iAP2 protocol, CarPlay).

My question is: **does BlueZ supports this kind of pairing? Where to find some information on that?**

What I have now:

- OBB Pairing **working flawlessly from the iOS side** (e.g. after USB connection established for the first time, I have my Linux device in "My Devices" bluetooth section of the phone).
- On Linux accessory's side I'm receiving iPhone's **mac address and linkkey** and writing it to ***/var/lib/bluetooth/${self_mac_addr}/${recieved_iphones_mac_addr}/info*** file. As a result, I'm able to see the device as "paired" on restarting `bluetoothd` service.

What I want to accomplish:

- Have iPhone added to the Linux device's bluez "paired" section without restarting `bluetoothd`.
- Receive iPhone's name to write to the aforementioned file (now I'm using mac address as a name).

Comment: Is this a rooted iOS device? Core Bluetooth doesn't support OOB pairing.